# How do I create a scatter plot with ordered character variables on the x-axis using plot() in r?

Tags: r, plot

My data kind of looks like this (except in a table imported from excel):

x values: E, D, D, C, B, A, A

y values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8

I get 'Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values'.
I tried to use `plot(factor(x), y, type = "p")` and am still getting a line instead of a point and a bar where there are two values for the same variable. Making it an ordered list by using `factored<-factor(x), ordered = TRUE` then plotting `plot(factored, y, type = "p")` also seems to have no effect and it defaults to alphabetical.

Any help using the plot function would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to factor your x variable, so that they are associated with a certain level, e.g A -> 1 , B-> 2 and so on.

You plot using the numeric of the factor and label the x-axis with the levels:

```
x = c("A","A","B","C","D","D","E")
y = c(0,1,2,3,5,7,8)

x=factor(x)

plot(as.numeric(x),y,xaxt="n")
axis(1,1:length(levels(x)),levels(x))
```

[image]

If you would like them to appear in the order it appears in x and not sorted alphabetically, for example:

```
x = c("E","D","D","A","A","C","B")
y = c(8,5,7,0,1,3,2)
# or you specify it specifically, levels = c(....)
x=factor(x,levels=unique(x))

plot(as.numeric(x),y,xaxt="n")
axis(1,1:length(levels(x)),levels(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But sorry, i just realised that my example was bad I should have used x = E, D, D, C, B, A, A. The graph would then become automatically alphabetical but how do i keep it in the order it originally was?

Answer (score 2):

If you use package `ggplot2`, the graph can be plotted even if `x` is not a factor, like in [StupidWolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041663/8245406). Note that I create the data.frame with argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image]